# Android is always rebooting after random timeinterval, when OpenCV CameraBridgeViewBase is used

Tags: android, opencv, nexus-4

I wrote a very simple app for Android, witch is using OpenCV for Android (in Java). I am using CameraBridgeViewBase and the adequate callbacks for processing the images. But if I use the app, after the estimation of a random time the Android os reboots. The version of the plattform is 4.3, the device is Nexus 4.

Are there any ideas, how could this happen? What can cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to modifie the Android version, with 4.2.2 it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a stack overflow and/or out of memory. I've had similar issues, although not rebooting.
Be sure to release all bitmaps as soon as you are done with them. A way to avoid excessive memory use when doing image processing, is to use the same bitmap object to get the data each time, instead of making a new one for each frame.

Comment: I use the same bitmap object to get the data each time too.